# Is there a way to get an applied input mask from an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the input mask that was applied to different elements using Josh Bush's Masked Input Plugin (https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) so that I can re-apply them to cloned elements.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You could store the mask as a `data-mask` attribute on the element.  Then you get it later, when you need it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately I'm writing an add-on for another script so I don't believe I have access to that information before it's applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up patching the maskedInput function to add the applied mask in a data attribute attached to the input element like this:

```
function patchMask() {
    var plugin = jQuery.fn.mask;
    jQuery.fn.mask = function(mask) {
        jQuery(this.get(0)).attr('data-mask', mask);
        return plugin.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kodie/kvbn20t8/6/

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are no methods in plugin's api to do that. I can suggest to do monkey patching of `$.fn.mask` like so http://jsfiddle.net/fbeeL2ft/2/. Not sure that it's helpful in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up going your route but just a little different. I patched the maskedInput function to add the applied mask in a data attribute attached to the input element like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kodie/kvbn20t8/

Comment: Your solution looks better))